Перенос тире после точки или двоеточия
На Грамоте и ещё в нескольких источниках есть правило, которое гласит, что "нельзя переносить на другую строку пунктуационные знаки, кроме тире, стоящего после точки или после двоеточия перед второй частью прерванной прямой речи".
Получается, что тире после точки или двоеточия с прямой речью перенести можно, но нужно ли? :) Допускается не значит поощряется. Есть ли какие-то рекомендации на этот счёт или варианты перенести и не переносить абсолютно равноправны?
